# Azure Cosmos DB using Gremlin.Net - Error submitting query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Using the sample code from Gremlin.net (V 3.3.2) I'm trying to connect to Cosmos DB. I receive the error below when task.Wait() executes:

"WebSocketException: The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected"

Any ideas why this is failing? Same code works fine with Amazon Neptune.

```
var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(hostname, port, enableSsl: true,username: "/dbs/" + database + "/colls/" + collection,password: authKey);

using (var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, new GraphSON2Reader(), new GraphSON2Writer(), GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType))

var task = gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query.Value);
task.Wait();
```

Comment: Host name is different than for Document API, it should look like `your-account.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com`

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. The Microsoft example here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-dotnet-graphexplorer has the wrong host name.

Comment: @RickJN You could add an answer here to help more communities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tom mentioned, posting an answer

When you are creating the client the hostname should be different from the documentdb which is something like

**`sample.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com`**

the code will look like

```
 private static GremlinServer GetGremlinServer(IConfigurationRoot builder)
 {
            var hostname = builder["cosmosDBConnection:gremlinEndpoint"];
            var port = builder.GetValue<int>("cosmosDBConnection:gremlinPort", 443);
            var authKey = builder["cosmosDBConnection:authKey"];
            var databaseId = builder["cosmosDBConnection:databaseId"];
            var graphId = builder["cosmosDBConnection:graphId"];

            var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(hostname, port, enableSsl: true, username: $"/dbs/{databaseId}/colls/{graphId}", password: authKey);
            return gremlinServer;
 }
```

Comment: Also note that as of today the hostname is incorrect if you use the Microsoft quickstart to generate the Gremlin Console from the Azure dashboard.